# Customizing inline enumerate with enumitem still not working?

Tags: lists, enumitem

I have the latest version of the `enumitem` package and I'm trying to use different labels for enumerate lists which are set as normal lists and enumerate lists which are set inline. However, it doesn't seem to work (one customization overwrites the other), and I've already asked a question about this where it turned out to be due to a bug.

However, I still can't get it to work. I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{%
  label=\arabic*.,
}
\setlist*[enumerate,1]{%
  label=(\roman*),
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate*}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

and what I get is:

[image]

Either I don't understand how to use the `\setlist` to get this to work, or the bug still remains. I can't figure out which.

Comment: The documentation says explicitly that "that labels and settings [of the inline lists] are shared with the displayed lists". So if you want independant settings you should create a new list with `\newlist`. Beside this `\setlist*` is not for the starred list variant but "The starred form `\setlist*` *adds* the settings to previous ones."

Comment: Aha, so _that's_ how you were meant to do it! I mistakenly assumed that the starred version of `\setlist` dealt with the starred versions of `itemize`, `enumerate`, etc. Thanks for clearing this out. Could any of you please provide an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Nothing can say it better than the manual.

> The three inline lists have types enumerate*, itemize*, and description*, which are
>   available always, even without the package option inline (which just defines three
>   environments with these names).
>
> The starred form `\setlist*` adds the settings to previous ones.

You should create a `\newlist` instead and there is no more need to put the `inline` option unless you want to use the predefined lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{%
  label=\arabic*.,
}

\newlist{inlinelist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist*[inlinelist,1]{%
  label=(\roman*),
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{enumerate}

\begin{inlinelist}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{inlinelist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I managed to completely confuse myself by assuming that `enumerate*` and `\setlist*` was somehow related. Thanks for showing how it's meant to be used. =)

Comment: Is it possible to automatically insert some symbol at end of each item?

Answer (score 11):

Easy control using "shortlabels" option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1.]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate*}[(i)]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to create an extra new list environment, you could use `etoolbox` like the following:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}

  \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*.}
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{enumerate*}{%
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\roman*)}
  }
  \AfterEndEnvironment{enumerate*}{%
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*.}
  }

  \begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{enumerate*}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
  \end{enumerate*}

  \end{document}
```