# Add same text to each item

Tags: enumitem

I have a question. I have list which each item contain same text.

For example:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SAMETEXT
2. Fusce blandit, orci vel cursus mollis, elit dui tristique purus, eget dapibus leo neque id mi. SAMETEXT
3. Quisque vehicula consequat elit in mattis. SAMETEXT
```

Each item contain "SAMETEXT". Is there any way to auto-display this text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method with `patching`, using a specialized `enumerate` environment, to prevent 'polution' for the patched `\item` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\TextToAppend}{\textbf{Don't do this at home}}

\newlist{dontdothislist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[dontdothislist,1]{label={\arabic*.}}


\xapptocmd{\dontdothislist}{%
\xpretocmd{\enddontdothislist}{\ifnumgreater{\value{dontdothislisti}}{0}{\TextToAppend}{}}{\typeout{Yes}}{\typeout{Nope}}
\xpretocmd{\item}{\ifnumgreater{\value{dontdothislisti}}{0}{\TextToAppend}{}}{\typeout{Yes}}{\typeout{Nope}}
}{}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla
\item Blo
\item Blu
\item Ble
\item Bli
\end{enumerate}

\begin{dontdothislist}
\item Bla
\item Blo
\item Blu
\item Ble
\item Bli Blu Blo Bla Ble
\end{dontdothislist}


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There might be issues with nested lists, perhaps ... did not test this

Comment: Can the space between the appended item and the text be removed? For example, `1. Bla Don't do this at home`, to be `1. BlaDon't do this at home`

Comment: @user: Why should one want to have this space removed?

Comment: It is because I need to append a dot. So a space before it would be not right. I have two list implementations, on one of them I need a dot appended to each item. But on the other I do not. Noticed both lists contains the same items. This way I declare `\newcommand{\listcontents}[1]{\item first \item second}` and call each one of the my implementations as `begin{listwithdot}\listcontents\end{listwithdot}` and on the other place I need the list items without a dot, I call the other list implementation  `begin{listwithoutdot}\listcontents\end{listwithoutdot}`

Comment: @user: I fear, I can't help you here

Answer (score 4):

Unless you just mean something very simple like this, rather than patching every list

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\sametext}{The world is your oyster}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \sametext
\item Fusce blandit, orci vel cursus mollis, elit dui tristique purus, eget dapibus leo neque id mi. \sametext
\item Quisque vehicula consequat elit in mattis. \sametext
\end{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\sametext}{The world is your kitchen}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \sametext
\item Fusce blandit, orci vel cursus mollis, elit dui tristique purus, eget dapibus leo neque id mi. \sametext
\item Quisque vehicula consequat elit in mattis. \sametext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to I needn't write \sametext, but the text is there automatic.

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to patch the `\item` macro by hand. In this case I delimited the patched `\item` macro to collect all items, while inserting the desired text (declared by `\everyitem`) everytime, into a token register and then print it with the use of a plain `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\ltx@item\item
\newtoks\EI@toks
\newtoks\EI@items
\def\EI@item{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \EI@item@}
\bgroup\catcode`\^^M=12 %
  \gdef\EI@item@#1^^M{%
    \global\EI@items=\expandafter{\the\EI@items\ltx@item#1 \the\EI@toks}%
    \endgroup}%
\egroup
\newcommand{\everyitem}[1]{\global\EI@toks{#1}}

\newenvironment{sametextlist}{%
  \let\item\EI@item
}{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \the\EI@items
  \end{enumerate}
}
\makeatother

\parindent0em
\everyitem{SAMETEXT}

\begin{document}
The \verb+sametextlist+ environment will print the text declared in the \verb+\everyitem+ macro after every use of the \verb+\item+ macro:

\begin{sametextlist}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  \item Fusce blandit, orci vel cursus mollis, elit dui tristique purus, eget dapibus leo neque id mi.
  \item Quisque vehicula consequat elit in mattis.
\end{sametextlist}

The usage of the \verb+\item+ macro isn't affected in the other environments:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  \item Fusce blandit, orci vel cursus mollis, elit dui tristique purus, eget dapibus leo neque id mi.
  \item Quisque vehicula consequat elit in mattis.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

Here, I define the environment `renumerate`, which takes as a mandatory argument the repeated text.  In my MWE, I invoke `enumerate` to show how redefinitions of `\item` do not extend outside of the `renumerate` environment. No packages necessary!

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svitem\item
\newcommand\newitem{\savetext\svitem}%
\newenvironment{renumerate}[1]
{%
  \def\savetext{#1}%
  \renewcommand\item{\let\item\newitem\svitem}%
  \begin{enumerate}%
}
{\savetext\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{renumerate}{My repeated text}
\item doe.
\item reh.
\item mi.
\end{renumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item doe.
\item reh.
\item mi.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Nesting `renumerate` works but may not give quite what is expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svitem\item
\newcommand\newitem{\savetext\svitem}
\let\savetext\relax
\newenvironment{renumerate}[1]
{%
  \def\savetext{#1}%
  \renewcommand\item{\let\item\newitem\svitem}%
  \begin{enumerate}%
}
{\savetext\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{renumerate}{My repeated text}
\item doe.
\item reh.
  \begin{renumerate}{\textbf{Now for something different!}}
  \item X.
  \item Y.
  \item Z.
  \end{renumerate}
\item mi.
\end{renumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I use inline enumeration, it only appends the text to my last inline item, not each inline item. I use the inline from [Customizing inline enumerate with enumitem still not working?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103086/customizing-inline-enumerate-with-enumitem-still-not-working) ``\newlist{inlinelist}{enumerate*}{1} \setlist*[inlinelist]{label=\arabic*}``

Comment: @user This is sufficiently different from the current question that I think a new question would be in order.  Make sure you give a full minimum working example to demonstrate it.